# Send email with attachments using intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I would like to send mail with attached image to the same address.

Comment: please Do little bit surfing before ask the question..
this ans is available on stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974987/how-to-send-an-email-with-a-file-attachment-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email

Comment: @Concentrated_Attitude: Where do I put the email address of the sender please?

Answer (score 1):

use below code hope it will help you

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("application/image");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{strEmail}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test Subject"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From My App"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Myimage.jpeg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: Where do I put the email address of the sender please?

Comment: why you want email address of sender when reciever recieves it he automatically gets sender address

Comment: cause your using intent to send email then when you call this code automatically default app of EMAIL will open and the account which is signed in in that email app will be your sender email address

Comment: you cannot mention sender email address you can mention receiver email address onlly

Answer (score 0):

Check out the android development training for more information and examples [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html)

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// The intent does not have a URI, so declare the "text/plain" MIME type
emailIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
new String[] {"jon@example.com"}); // recipients
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message text");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
Uri.parse("content://path/to/emai/attachment"));
// You can also attach multiple items by passing an ArrayList of Uris
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: Where do I put the email address of the sender please?

Comment: You don't need to set the sender address. The e-mail application that receives the intent will set the sender address.