# Android email attachment missing

Tags: android, email, android-intent, email-attachments

I was trying to send an email with image as attachment.I see the item attached to the mail while sending , but in the inbox i see just the mail message but attachment missing. Please help me if my code went wrong somewhere

```
    ArrayList<String> fetchList= new ArrayList<>();
    fetchList= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Uri");
    ArrayList<Uri> uriList=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<fetchList.size();i++){
        uriList.add(i,Uri.parse(fetchList.get(i)));
    }

    public void sendClicked(View view) {
    String emailBody =textMessage.getText().toString();
    String emailSubject=textSubject.getText().toString();
    String Email_To[]=new String[]{"kittutanu@yahoo.co.in"};

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setType("text/plain"); 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, Email_To);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);
    if (uriList != null) {
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList);
    }
    try {
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with multipart/alternative or multipart/mixed type?

Here is an example [How to send an email with a file attachment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974987/how-to-send-an-email-with-a-file-attachment-in-android)

Comment: nope. what are they. thanks fr the example but it has the same logic as mine.

Comment: You can read about Content Types here http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html