# export file from app

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

I am trying to create this app where the user fills a form and then exports the form using email. However, I don't know how to go about it. I have searched online, but have reached so many dead ends. Is that possible or there is absolutely no way to export the xml page as a document? I tried using intent chooser, and extra text to get the string, but it just prints the string as words, and not into a file that can be exported.

Comment: You are talking about exporting files and then about sending emails. What exactly is it that you are looking for? What's your best shot so far?

Comment: Did you check this answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974987/how-to-send-an-email-with-a-file-attachment-in-android

You can save your file on the filesystem and pass the path in the intent.

Comment: @e4c5 i mean when the user fills the form, and then tries to export the filled form by e mail

Comment: @AjitPratapSingh so i save the filled form on the filesystem and then pass what path?

Comment: @AjitPratapSingh the link you gave is to send a file on the phone, I want the filled form

Comment: Perhaps it's a matter of getting your terminonlogy right? You want someone to fill a form on your app and you want to send that as an email. The term export probably shouldn't be here. THat's what's confusing everyone trying to help.  Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-can-i-send-emails-from-my-android-application    The body of the email is something you will have to generate by adding your form fields together.

Comment: @e4c5 I'm sorry, you don't get me. Say this is a questionnaire app, the user goes on and fills the questionnaire, and then clicks send to send the filled form to whoever. I know how to use intent, I just need to know how to export the filled form to whoever.

Comment: Like I said , there is no export, you just need to email it. If you already know how to use intents what are you waiting for?

Comment: @e4c5 because it does not send the filled form

Comment: Refer my previous comment. Sometimes you have to write a bit of code "The body of the email is something you will have to generate by adding your form fields together"

Comment: do you mean like editText.getText.toString()? because it just takes the user's input one at a time, not sending it all at once as a document

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make some document file like pdf or doc programatically and then attach that file in email.

Comment: you mean like convert the page to a document?how?

Comment: I mean you can put your form content in some file and then attach it to email.
Please check this link for your reference (generate pdf)
http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Blog/post/2012/06/15/Generating-PDFs-Dynamically-on-Android.aspx

Comment: thank you! that looks like what I am looking for. Will read through and mark if it answers my need!