# I want to send an email(javamail)with image attachment

Tags: android, image, jakarta-mail, attachment

Im able to send email, just attachment part left..
First I'm taking picture and I want to send that picture as attachment.
please help

Here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ReportFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    View view;
    Button sendBtn;
    public  String s="Report sent";
    int count=0;
    Session session = null;
    ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
    Context context = null;
    EditText reciep, sub, msg,user,pass;
    TextView check;
    public   String uname,password,rec, subject, textMessage;
    String[] items={"Police","Hospital","Fire-Station"};

    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888;
    Button cameraBtn;
    ImageView imageView;

    Spinner spin;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report, container, false);
    context = getActivity();
    spin = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);
    sub = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    msg = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
          pass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);

    cameraBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });

    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spin.setAdapter(aa);


    sendBtn= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            // convert byte array to Bitmap

           Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
}

public  boolean isOnline()
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(!isOnline()) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else if(sub.getText().length()==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Subject cannot be empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(msg.getText().length()<10)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter atleast 10 characters in Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(pass.getText().length()==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
     {
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        String emailData = activity.getEmail();
        uname = emailData;
        //uname = user.getText().toString();
        password = pass.getText().toString();
        //rec = reciep.getText().toString();
        // rec ="amey.palkar1@gmail.com";

        subject = sub.getText().toString();
        textMessage = msg.getText().toString();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Authenticator a = null;
        a = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(uname, password);

            }
        };

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, a);

        pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Sending Mail...", true);
        RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
        task.execute();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    if(items[i].equals("Police"))
    {
        rec="police.goodsamaritan@gmail.com";
    }
    else if(items[i].equals("Hospital"))
    {
        rec="hospitasl.goodsamaritan@gmail.com";
    }
    else if(items[i].equals("Fire-Station"))
    {
        rec="fire.goodsamaritan@gmail.com";
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}

class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



        try
        {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(uname));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(rec));
            message.setSubject(subject);
           message.setContent(textMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(message);




        } catch(MessagingException e) {

            s="Username Password is wrong";
            count=100;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pdialog.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        s="Report Sent";
        count=0;
    }
}

}
```

This is my code 
Please help me someone how to add attachment in this code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974987/how-to-send-an-email-with-a-file-attachment-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Use something like the following to construct the body of the message:

```
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

    MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    // messageBody contains html that references image
    // using something like <img src="cid:XXX"> where
    // "XXX" is an identifier that you make up to refer
    // to the image
    htmlPart.setText(messageBody, "utf-8", "html");
    multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

    MimeBodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    // imageFile is the file containing the image
    imgPart.attachFile(imageFile);
    // or, if the image is in a byte array in memory, use
    // imgPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
    //      new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "image/whatever")));

    // "XXX" below matches "XXX" above in html code
    imgPart.setContentID("<XXX>");
    multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);

    message.setContent(multipart);
```

Also, you'll want to fix some of these other [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: Thank you so much.. But can you please tell me how to add the image that I'm capturing... I want to send the image after capturing.. How to add bitmap as attachment?

Comment: You need to convert the bitmap into one of the standard image formats.  I don't know how to do that.  Once you have the bytes in jpeg or gif or png format, attach them as described above.